# Convert Linq Expression into the string with given property values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to compile my linq Expression (Expression\\>) into the string.

This works fine:

```
Expression<Func<MyTestClass, bool>> q5 = x => x.Prop1 == "abc" || x.Prop2 == 123;
```

By calling q5.Body.ToString() I get expected output:

> ((x.Prop1 == "abc") OrElse (x.Prop2 == 123))

However a problem starts when I replace the right part of any BinaryExpression by more complicated values. For example:

```
    var item = new MyTestClass {Prop2 = 123};
        var prop2 = 23;
        string prop = "abc";

        Expression<Func<MyTestClass, bool>> q5 = x => x.Prop1 == prop || x.Prop2 == item.Prop2;
```

The output becomes:

> ((x.Prop1 == value(Tests.LambdaTests+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).prop) OrElse (x.Prop2 == value(Tests.LambdaTests+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).item.Prop2))

I understand more or less why the Expression compiles into this and probably I need go through all expression parts by looking for a MemberExpression type and evaluate member value, but is where a more simple way to get something similar like in the first example?
All I need is to replace 'value(Tests.LambdaTests+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).item.Prop2)' by it's value.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No. `item` is a reference type and it must be resolved at runtime. What if you set `item.Prop2 = 456` later on? The compiler doesn't know when q5 will be evaluated so if you were to run

```
Expression<Func<MyTestClass, bool>> q5 = x => x.Prop1 == prop || x.Prop2 == item.Prop2;
Console.WriteLine(q5.Body);
item.Prop2 = 456;
Console.WriteLine(q5.Body);
```

you would get two identical

> ((x.Prop1 == value(Tests.LambdaTests+<>c__DisplayClass0).prop) OrElse (x.Prop2 =
>   = value(Tests.LambdaTests+<>c__DisplayClass0).item.Prop2))

By keeping value types in your lambda, the compiler knows it won't change and any time it is evaluated, it will always check against `"abc"` and `123`.